# How to run server.js written in js with Node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, sockets

i have a file with nodejs language which i found in the internet, i want to run it, but i don't know how to run it. i tryed to run with cmd command: node server.js but it not work.

file `server.js`

```js
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
server   = require('http').createServer(),
io       = require('socket.io').listen(server),

users = {}, socks = {};

function Uid() { this.id = ++Uid.lastid; }

Uid.lastid = 0;

//Handle users
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

 // Event received by new user
 socket.on('join', function (recv) {

  if (!recv.user) {
   socket.emit('custom_error', { message: 'User not found or invalid' });
   return;
  }

  // The user already exists
  if (users[recv.user]) {
   socket.emit('custom_error', { message: 'The user '+ recv.user +' already exists' });
   return;
  }

  // If there is users online, send the list of them
  if (Object.keys(users).length > 0)
   socket.emit('chat', JSON.stringify( { 'action': 'usrlist', 'user': users } ));

  // Set new uid
  uid = new Uid();
  socket.user = recv.user;

  // Add the new data user
  users[socket.user] = {'uid': Uid.lastid, 'user': socket.user, 'name': recv.name, 'status': 'online'}
  socks[socket.user] = {'socket': socket}

  // Send new user is connected to everyone
  socket.broadcast.emit('chat', JSON.stringify( {'action': 'newuser', 'user': users[socket.user]} ));
 });

 // Event received when user want change his status
 socket.on('user_status', function (recv) {
  users[socket.user].status = recv.status;
  socket.broadcast.emit('chat', JSON.stringify( {'action': 'user_status', 'user': users[socket.user]} ));
 });

 // Event received when user is typing
 socket.on('user_typing', function (recv) {
  var id  = socks[recv.user].socket.id;
  io.sockets.socket(id).emit('chat', JSON.stringify( {'action': 'user_typing', 'data': users[socket.user]} ));
 });

 // Event received when user send message to another
 socket.on('message', function (recv) {
  var id  = socks[recv.user].socket.id;
  var msg = {'msg': recv.msg, 'user': users[socket.user]};
  io.sockets.socket(id).emit('chat', JSON.stringify( {'action': 'message', 'data': msg} ));
 });

 // Event received when user has disconnected
 socket.on('disconnect', function () {
  socket.broadcast.emit('chat', JSON.stringify( {'action': 'disconnect', 'user': users[socket.user]} ));
  //socket.broadcast.emit('chat', JSON.stringify( {'action': 'offline', 'user': users[socket.user]} ));
  delete users[socket.user];
  delete socks[socket.user];
 });
});

//Listen to the server port
server.listen(port, function () {
  var addr = server.address();
  console.log('jquery-chat server listening and ready');
});
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? What does it means "but it not work"?

Comment: yes, i get an error: Cant not find module "socket.io" at...

Comment: Then you do not have socket.io module installed. Check out this link to install socket.io http://socket.io/download/

Answer (score 2):

To execute a javascript using NodeJS you have to use the `node <filename>` command from the command prompt/terminal.

You're using a relative path. Change `node server.js` to `node "/full/path/to/server.js"`.

For example, if server.js is located in `C:\myserver\server.js`, then run:

```
node "C:\myserver\server.js"
```

Comment: What is it saying when you try it?

Comment: not found 'socket.io'. i am still learning about nodejs, so i don't know where to find socket.io packet

Comment: Socket.io is a module that you can install using NPM (Node Package Manager). Take a look at this link, it will tell you how to install Socket.IO for node. http://socket.io/download/

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `socket.io`.
Run in terminal:

```
npm install socket.io
```